# how to add layer list on an user uploaded image?

Tags: android, layer-list

i want to add effects from my layer-list on an user upload image.In this code i can only do effect on an image from drawable i want to change that to an user upload image
**this is my xml file for effect**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/icn" android:gravity="center" android:alpha="0.1"/>
</item>

<item android:top="300dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    >
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-12">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="?android:colorBackground"/>
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

**this is my xml file for displaying the final image**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bgImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_height="290dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a [`LayerDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable) by code instead of xml.

Just new a `LayerDrawable` and call its `addLayer` method to add `Drawable`s, and all the properties you set from xml can also be set in code, such as `setLayerInset` methods.

For example, define the drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:fromDegrees="-12">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid
            android:color="?android:colorBackground"/>
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Get the drawable from code:

```
Drawable myDrawable;
Resources res = getResources();
try {
   myDrawable = Drawable.createFromXml(res, res.getXml(R.xml.my_drawable));
} catch (Exception ex) {
   Log.e("Error", "Exception loading drawable"); 
}
```

Create `LayerDrawable` and addLayer into it:

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable();
layerDrawable.addLayer(userDrawable); // userDrawable is from the user upload image
layerDrawable.addLayer(myDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by combine bitmaps of user photo and layer-list drawable.

Here is example:

```
Bitmap effects = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.effect_name);
Bitmap[] parts = new Bitmap[2];
parts[0] = userImage; //Bitmap
parts[1] = effects; //Bitmap
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(parts[0].getWidth() * 2, parts[0].getHeight() * 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
Paint paint = new Paint();
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(parts[i], parts[i].getWidth() * (i % 2), parts[i].getHeight() * (i / 2), paint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**first of all Create a layer list like this**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background" />
    <item 
        <shape>
            <solid/>
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#225786" />
            <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
            <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
        </shape>
    </item> 
  </layer-list>
```

just want a background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:tileMode="repeat" >

</bitmap>
```

And finally add background on **ImageView**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bgImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_height="290dp"/>
```